# Manage publishing of several very similar apps on the App Store

Tags: ios, release-management

I need to find an easy way to maintain a set of different iOS apps but that they will be very similar one to another. Too similar actually, the differences will be just regarding the content.

Following the typical way of releasing/updating an app, it would imply:

1. Create a "core project" of the app with all the functionality and UI.
2. Create n projects that reuses the core project. Every project would just provide a DB with different content.
3. Having to release/update every single project/app to the AppStore

This would be too time consuming. Is there a tool or a methodology that can help us speed up the process and help the maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built in process for this is to create multiple targets in a single project. Each target will have its own info plist, etc.